# SSL Error on nginx based ssl terminator

Tags: ssl, nginx

I receive the following nginx log frequently and unable to get any suitable answer from google search. My nginx is having a valid SSL certificate.

> Jul 15 08:21:58 web-lb01 WEB_LB01_443: 2016/07/15 08:21:58 [info]
>   5753#0: *7101 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140943F2:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message:SSL alert
>   number 10) while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: when this is happening ? client to nginx ssl connection or nginx to upstream ssl connection ?

Comment: client to nginx only

Comment: May be issue with the openssl library
 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=514694

Comment: @Suyash Jain I'm seeing the same issue for my nginx setup. Have you been able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on the Ciphers and protocols like TLS1.2,TLS1.1, TLS1.0 are enabled . SSL handshaking comprises of not only the SSL certificate but also a common set of ciphers and protocols are negotiated between the client and the server for further encryption.